# tableViewController in iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to develop the `TableView` programmatically.

I want to add section header to my `tableView`.

It's added but overlapping with the `tableCell`.

But when I develop the code through storyboard it's coming in proper way.

Please suggest me how I can separate `tableView` row with the `tableview` section?

My Code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
    [tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,tableView.bounds.size.width,44)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    tempLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

    if (section==0) 
         tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Introduction"];
    else if(section==1)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Nuron"];

    else if(section==2)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Brain Developoment"];

    else if(section==3)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sensation &Perception"];

    else if(section==4)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stress"];

    else if(section==5)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sleep"];

    else if(section==6)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Diagonistic Method"];

    else if(section==7)
        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Potential Therapy"];


    [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];

       return tempView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't implement [`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a) iOS assumes that the height of your header is 0 points.
Implement it and return the desired height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set section background color to clear color and that is why it is overlapping.

```
[tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whitecolor]];//or any other color
```

let me check it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you sir.Also that time I made a mistake in .xib file.I made that tableView style as grouped.

Comment: then please upvote my answer and accept it my friend.